# HIVE - Split large ordered query result set into multiple sequential files

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-redshift

I am using HIVE for an ETL process on raw data on S3. I generate structured output data which is sorted before loading into another database(redshift).
The data needs to be loaded into redshift in a sorted sequence of manageable chunks, say 5-10 Billion rows per chunk, where the total dataset is 100s of billion records.

I am looking for a way for hive to sort the data, and then break it into smaller manageable chunks which can be uploaded individually in a sorted sequence.
So far I have not been able to come up with an approach which allows me to do that. Number of reducers in hive is forced 1 with I use an "Oder By" clause so I get one mammoth file! ***There is no way I can move such a huge file out of S3 to uncompress/split/recompress/reload as I don't have a place to do all that.***

Using "Cluster By" generates chunks that are internally sorted, but there is no guarantee of sequence between the chunks.

The sort-by key is a composite alphanumeric key, and the distinct count is too large to be partitioned by.

***Issues with cluster/distribute:***

The problem with cluster and distribute options from my understanding is that the distribution happens based on a hash of the distribution key. If x < y, then hash(x) is not guaranteed to be less than hash(y). So across the files that get generated, by data is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading S3 from hive:** 
Can you Specify an external file for hive (when you are using Order By hive generates one large file) using `LOCATION 's3://<bucket>/etc` so then hive will put it directly into S3.

**Loading manually:** When you use Sort By then the data in one reducer should be sorted. Did you try using a  separate  so the data gets distributed by a certain key while they are being sorted.

The Distribution Key should be chosen in such a way that all your records which should be in one bucket does not go you any other file.

Comment: I already have generated a single very large file in S3. But I cannot load it in one go, which is why I need a way to break it. Now the problem with a distribution key is that the data is distributed based on a hash of the key. So let's say my data is sorted by name. The hash of the name going to different files will break the sort order across files. Each file will be sorted by name, but across files the data is no longer sorted..

Comment: Yes, your distribution key should logically divide the data. For example, suppose you have marks of students in a school - if you partition by class and sort my marks then you are still okay to use the data. Here a global sort ordering on Marks will not help you. If you can, share the source data model, that way some suggestions  might come up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bucketing the table and that would create some number of near equally sized partitions that would be more easily manipulated.

```
 Create table mytable (
 record_ID string,
 var1 double
 )
 clustered by record_ID into 100 buckets;


set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
from my_other_table
insert overwrite table mytable
select *;
```

Additionally you could create a random number and partition by it as well.  This would be equally easy using the random() udf in hive.

Comment: Clustering by record_ID into 100 buckets puts record 1 and 101 into the same file. record 2 and 102 go into the same file. This breaks the sort order that I am looking for.

Comment: You need to create a variable that preserves your order and then partition a table on it.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution might be to use the bash split command on the full sorted output to break it into smaller files.

The following is taken from the man page:

```
NAME
       split - split a file into pieces

SYNOPSIS
       split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]

DESCRIPTION
       Output  fixed-size  pieces  of  INPUT  to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT is -, read
       standard input.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -a, --suffix-length=N
              use suffixes of length N (default 2)

       -b, --bytes=SIZE
              put SIZE bytes per output file

       -C, --line-bytes=SIZE
              put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file

       -d, --numeric-suffixes
              use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic

       -l, --lines=NUMBER
              put NUMBER lines per output file

       --verbose
              print a diagnostic just before each output file is opened

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit

       SIZE may be (or may be an integer optionally followed by) one of following: KB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, and so on for G, T, P, E, Z, Y.
```

So, something like:

split -l 5000000000 filename

might work.

Comment: I already mentioned in my post that I dont have the space to take this file off S3 to do this and put it back. That single file could easily end up being 1TB